# how to exclude 'enter' while taking a char input in c?

Tags: c, char

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Enter a : ");
    scanf("%c",&a);
    printf("Enter b : ");
    scanf("%c",&b);
    printf("Enter c : ");
    scanf("%c",&c);
    printf("Enter d : ");
    scanf("%c",&c);
}
```

output:

```
C:\Users\Saran\Desktop>gcc new.c
C:\Users\Saran\Desktop>a
Enter a : s
Enter b : Enter c : c
Enter d :
```

if this is my code, it takes first char into variable 'a' and then if i press enter the variable 'b' takes enter as its input. how to overcome this problem?

Comment: `scanf("%c",&a);` --> `scanf(" %c",&a);`

Comment: another option (not good as scanf(" %c")) is add getchar() after each scanf

Comment: Or flush `stdin` using `while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);`

Comment: Or like [this](http://ideone.com/AubUG3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C language all the input operation done with the help of ASCII code. <kbd>Enter</kbd> key have ASCII code `10`, when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key then `scanf("%c",&b)` convert it into ASCII and store `10`. You can see by printing `printf("%d",b)`.

In your case you can use alternative input-string `getchar()` for handling <kbd>Enter</kbd> like

```
int main() {

    char a,b,c,d;
    printf("Enter a : ");
    scanf("%c",&a);
    getchar();
    printf("Enter b : ");
    scanf("%c",&b);
    getchar();
    printf("Enter c : ");
    scanf("%c",&c);
    getchar();
    printf("Enter d : ");
    scanf("%c",&d);
    printf("\n print a - %c ",a);
    printf("\n print b - %c ",b);
    printf("\n print c - %c ",c);
    printf("\n print d - %c",d);


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Enter a : Enter b : Enter c : Enter d :
>   print a - m
>   print b - n
>   print c - 0
>   print d - p